# Which is the neatest and/or most effective approach to kill a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a task x that is executed continuously in a thread which will only stop when the boolean changes it's state to true. I have done some reading and there are 3 ways that I approach when killing threads that are in the code below. Which of the 3 methods is effective ? And if none of them aren't effective or correct kindly suggest a proper approach with some code for reference.

Below is the code :

```
public class MyTest {

private static class transaction {

     private String param1,param2,param3, param4, param5;

     public transaction (String param1,String param2,String param3,String param4,String param5){
         this.param1=param1;
         this.param2=param2;
         this.param3=param3;
         this.param4=param4;
         this.param5=param5;
     }

     public String getParam1(){
         return this.param1;
     }

     public String getParam2(){
         return this.param2;
     }

     public String getParam3(){
         return this.param3;
     }

     public String getParam4(){
         return this.param4;
     }

     public String getParam5(){
         return this.param5;
     }
}

public static void processBatch(String workerName){

    try{

        java.util.List <transaction> transactions= new java.util.LinkedList<transaction>();
        java.sql.ResultSet dbtrx=Database.db.execQuery((Object)"dbname.procname");

        while(dbtrx.next()){// Takes a snapshot of the pending payments in the table and stores it into the list.
            Object obj=new transaction (dbtrx.getString("col1"), dbtrx.getString("col2"), dbtrx.getString("col3"), dbtrx.getString("col4"), dbtrx.getString("col5"));
            transactions.add((transaction)obj);
            obj=null;
        }

        java.util.Iterator<transaction> iterate= transactions.iterator();

        /* Processes the pending batch payments*/
        while(iterate.hasNext()){
            transaction trx=iterate.next();
            /*Calls posting function here*/
            System.out.println(workerName+":- Param1 : "+trx.getParam1()+" - Param2 : " +trx.getParam2()+
                    " - Param3 : "+ trx.getParam3()+" - Param4 : "+ trx.getParam4()+" - Param5 : "+ trx.getParam5());
            iterate.remove();
        }

        /*cleaning object references*/
        dbtrx=null;
        transactions=null;
        iterate=null;

     }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
    volatile boolean stop=false;
    Object hold= new Object();
    new Thread("Batch Worker A"){
        @Override 
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                if(stop!=true){
                    processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }else{
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(0);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }catch(java.lang.InterruptedException e){
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }}.start();

    new Thread("Batch Worker B"){
        @Override 
        public void run(){
            try{
                while(stop!=true){
                    processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
                Thread.sleep(0);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }catch(java.lang.InterruptedException e){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
            }
        }}.start();

    new Thread("Batch Worker C"){
        @Override 
        public void run(){
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                if(stop!=true){
                    processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }else{
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }}.start();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Really, the best way is to code the thread to do what, and only what, you want done in the first place. That way, you won't have to interrupt or kill it. The question you should ask yourself is this -- why did I code this thread to do work I don't want it to do?

Comment: Ok Maybe I didn't get you to understand my issue properly. The example I have posted is just an arbitrary job or task. My main concern here is if I have an application that has a shutdown invocation, I would like to kill all the threads with in it neatly to avoid memory leaks. So basically I was trying to figure out the best way to approach the thread shutdown.

Comment: I understand. Why not just code the threads to terminate themselves when there is no useful work for them to do? The problem is that you have coded threads to do work that you don't want done. The solution is to fix the code in those threads so they only do work you *want* done and terminate themselves if there is no useful work you can do. The fact that you need to "reach into" the threads to "force" them to interrupt or terminate just shows that they were badly programmed in the first place. Threads should cooperate, not be at war.

Comment: Aha I think I get your point. So basically using the batch process example, If there are no records , the thread(s) shouldn't be running at all and if there are records it/they should. Nice approach and very neat, thank you for the advice.

Comment: 'if I have an application that has a shutdown invocation, I would like to kill all the threads with in it neatly to avoid memory leaks' - what OS do you plan to use that allows memory leaks on app/process termination?

Comment: @MartinJames Actually the application is a Web Application with a servletcontextlistener that is running in tomcat6. The servlet contains some threads that are initialized on initialize method and stopped on destroy method . Everytime I stop the application I check the error logs and get the error: 
"SEVERE: The web application [/AppName] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-Name] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of your examples, you aren't really killing the thread, you are stopping the batch from processing more items. 
To understand the difference, note that none of your methods would actually stop the thread while the thread is within the processBatch function.

There are some things to take note of:

- There is no point in calling Interrupt() on your current thread. The idea behind Interrupt is for external threads to call it. In your case, you can just as well throw an exception, or return from the run() function (which would shut down the thread automatically).
- Even interrupt() can't in many situations stop a thread if that thread is locked outside java ,such as thread waiting for IO (if not using NIO), including a socket, which is what the database connection is, you'll need to design a different way to stop a thread inside IO (usually by doing a timeout, but there are other ways).

if you goal is simply to stop the next batch from happing use the code from Joonas :

```
new Thread("Batch Worker A"){
@Override 
public void run() {
    while(!stop){
            processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}}.start();
```

if your goal is to interrupt the process while running the batch, you can just as well do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   var t =new Thread("Batch Worker A"){
      @Override 
      public void run() {
         processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
       }
   }.start(); 
   t.interrupt();
}
```

in general interrupt is the preferred method, and using a local scoped variable and anonymous classes is a really bad idea (use a static variable, or better an injected interface with a function to check if the thread should continue).

Comment: Sir, I must commend you for this , infact this is what I have been exactly looking for. I have always thought that the stopping the loop would eventually kill the thread. I always wanted of killing a thread on it's own and that is why I was invoking interrupt within itself. Just a clarification using your last example assuming I have a ServletContextListener that on initialization started the var t, will calling the var t.interrrupt on destroy actually kill the thread?

Comment: if you call t.interrupt() an InterruptedException will be thrown inside the t thread.
If there is nothing to catch the exception inside the t Thread, then the thread would stop with a thrown exception, if there is a catch phrase (which you should do), then the t Thread would stop at that point, where you can decide to either return from the run function (and hence kill the thread) or do something else.

Answer (score 6):

The recommended approach is to use the thread's interrupted flag to signal the thread loop to terminate. There's no reason to use *two* flags (`stopped` and the interrupted flag) where one will do, and you don't seem to be using the interrupted flag for anything else.

See the Java tutorial subject [Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) for a more extensive discussion and examples.

Comment: Thanks Ted for the clarification, I really get confused with all these  examples. I was using "Batch Worker A" via Kabutz killing thread example but it seems I hadn't go the concept well.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply this way:

```
new Thread("Batch Worker A"){
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        while(!stop){
                processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }}.start();
```

Alternatively, use `Thread.interrupt()` like so:

```
new Thread("Batch Worker A"){
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        while(!interrupted()){
                processBatch(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }}.start();
```

but then you need to keep reference to all the threads, and interrupt them all, so the boolean flag might be simpler (be sure to make it volatile).

Comment: Thanks Joonas for the simplifying them.